# How to create equal distance between discrete categories with different numbers per facet, using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

My aim is to have more or less equal distance between all the countries in the plot. For example, in the first category (**Increase**), the countries are dispersed. On the other hand, the countries in the second and third category are too close to each other.

This forces me to decrease the size of the text of the countries (e.g., "IS", "UK"...) and the estimates that are plotted (e.g., "1.5", "1.2"...). Thus once I extract this file to pdf or word, the reader cannot see clearly what are the names of the countries or the estimates. If i increase their size text, then the countries overlap and some estimates (especially the ones of the **Stable** category) touch the other estimates next to them.

Is there a way to get around this problem?

[image]

Here is the data and the code:

```
structure(list(cntry = structure(1:26, .Label = c("AU", "BE", 
"BG", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "EE", "GR", "ES", "FI", "FR", "HU", "IE", 
"IS", "IT", "LT", "LV", "NL", "NO", "PO", "PT", "RO", "SE", "SV", 
"SK", "UK"), class = "factor"), estimate = c(-4.08943257103804, 
0.264307961887035, -0.4008773217117, -1.91874959282838, -0.964527079847473, 
-4.30067253169461, -0.920426011686486, -0.0746109649703081, 1.03855028529355, 
-1.28691260252507, -3.21446990383498, -0.0381504621278269, 0.0286675062078212, 
1.46814093121697, -0.50165518722767, -0.787733440190981, 0.745627449639574, 
0.586929625060384, 0.191285070657763, 0.217512744502688, 1.35842665232147, 
0.358385446150237, -0.238203754070039, -1.59896322663246, 0.100424706108376, 
1.15585740391863), conf.low = c(-5.60117192484885, -0.840219073796263, 
-1.62699620711119, -3.64218275679053, -2.0989086744086, -6.58558173414225, 
-2.11216930433376, -0.986944473894656, 0.221565068594325, -2.69498298777435, 
-3.98554432677659, -1.10463119017979, -1.86828501326683, -1.18099254843252, 
-1.27464693464705, -2.24155213350216, -0.522730236481673, -0.479328474807381, 
-1.20651423960493, -0.461478316905123, -2.34340124131767, -0.458919023509462, 
-1.65550186084418, -3.35325169024894, -1.17499651445811, 0.0527941744160207
), conf.high = c(-2.57769321722723, 1.36883499757033, 0.825241563687791, 
-0.195316428866239, 0.169854514713651, -2.01576332924696, 0.271317280960783, 
0.83772254395404, 1.85553550199278, 0.121157782724206, -2.44339548089336, 
1.02833026592413, 1.92562002568248, 4.11727441086645, 0.271336560191708, 
0.666085253120201, 2.01398513576082, 1.65318772492815, 1.58908438092046, 
0.8965038059105, 5.0602545459606, 1.17568991580994, 1.1790943527041, 
0.155325236984016, 1.37584592667486, 2.25892063342124), crisis_f = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Increase", "Stable", 
"Decrease"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>%
  arrange(estimate) %>%
  mutate(label = replace(round(estimate, 1),cntry==1, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= estimate, fct_reorder(cntry, estimate, .desc = TRUE),label=label)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(hjust= -0.5, size=2.5)  + 
  geom_linerange(mapping=aes(xmin=conf.low , xmax=conf.high, y=cntry), width=0.1, size=.5, color="black") + 
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=estimate, y=cntry), size=2.3, shape=21, fill="black") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, color = "black", linetype= "dotted") +
  ggtitle(NULL) + xlab("Happiness") + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(crisis_f), scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom", shrink=F) +
  ylab("")   +
  theme_classic() +
  theme( 
    plot.title = element_text(color="Black", size=24, face="bold", hjust= 0.5), axis.title.x = element_text(color="Black", size=24, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="Black", size=20, face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size=10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=14),
    strip.text = element_text(face= "bold", size=17),
    plot.caption = element_text(size= 12),
    legend.justification=c(1,0),
    legend.position=c(1,0),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_rect(line = "solid"),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm")) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: If you replace `facet_wrap()` with `facet_grid()` you can use the `space = "free_x"` argument.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The issue is that `strip.position = "bottom" ` does not work if i use `facet_grid()`, it is not part of its arguments. I tried then to include it in the `theme()` section, but it did not work. Do you know what to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `facet_row` from `ggforce` which allows free scales and `strip.position='bottom'`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggforce)

p <- df %>%
  arrange(estimate) %>%
  mutate(label = replace(round(estimate, 1),cntry==1, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= estimate, fct_reorder(cntry, estimate, .desc = TRUE),label=label)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(hjust= -0.5, size=2.5)  + 
  geom_linerange(mapping=aes(xmin=conf.low , xmax=conf.high, y=cntry), width=0.1, size=.5, color="black") + 
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=estimate, y=cntry), size=2.3, shape=21, fill="black") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, color = "black", linetype= "dotted") +
  ggtitle(NULL) + xlab("Happiness") + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = 1)) +
  ylab("")   +
  theme_classic() +
  theme( 
    plot.title = element_text(color="Black", size=24, face="bold", hjust= 0.5), axis.title.x = element_text(color="Black", size=24, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="Black", size=20, face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size=10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=14),
    strip.text = element_text(face= "bold", size=17),
    plot.caption = element_text(size= 12),
    legend.justification=c(1,0),
    legend.position=c(1,0),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_rect(line = "solid"),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm")) + 
  coord_flip() 

p + ggforce::facet_row(vars(crisis_f), scales = 'free_x', space = 'free',strip.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was wondering whether it is also possible to widen the distance between all the estimates. That way i can increase the size of the country letters without them overlapping at each other.

Comment: @Jad, wouldn't simply increasing the width of the graph allow to avoid overlaps?